# Post to facebook newsfeed iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Googling around didn't do well for me.

I would like to know how to implement Facebook post to newsfeed using ARC, iOS 5 and Storyboarding without leaving/exiting the app.

Already tried the tutorial in developer.facebook.com and had a hard time getting this done.

Any references will do.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This [Facebook iOS tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) basically provides all the knowledge you need for making posts with the Facebook SDK. If you scroll down a bit, you'll see the code for posting to the newsfeed (hint: search for feedDialog).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Facebook SDK is not a trivial task. You need to put in the hours to understand it or just use sharekit. In future iOS may incorporate Facebook as it did with Twitter but for now you have to go to GITHUB and download the Facebook iOS code & hackbook sample.
The web page at [Facebook's developer pages for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) is the place to start learning.

If you have enough hours to burn you can get an implementation going in a couple of days. 
Regarding ARC you need to set the -fno-objc-arc compiler flags in build phases, compile sources for the Facebook .m files which are not ARC. Your own files can be written as ARC & mixed with the FB ones which are pre-ARC.